# "NetworkError: 404 Not Found in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

When I click on a link I have getting the data but my css pages, Js files and images are not working. Below I mention the link, route, controller and error(Firebug console). Please help me to clear this error.

Link from a page

```
<a href="customersocialpage/<?php echo $searchCustomer->customer_id; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($searchCustomer->firstname); ?></span> <?php echo ucfirst($searchCustomer->lastname); ?></h5></a>
```

routes.php

```
$router->get('customersocialpage/{id}', ['as' => 'custsocialpage', 'uses' => 'CustomersocialpageController@index']);
```

CustomersocialpageController.php

```
public function index($id)
    {
        dd($id);
        $customersocialpages = Customeraddress::where('customer_id', $id)->first();
        return view('pages.customersocialpage',['customersocialpages' => $customersocialpages]);
    }
```

Error

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://baselaravel.dev/customersocialpage/assets/img/demo/calendar_app.svg"
```

Link to CSS

```
{!!HTML::style('assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css')!!}
{!!HTML::style('assets/plugins/boostrapv3/css/bootstrap.min.css')!!}
{!!HTML::style('assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css')!!}
```

Link to JS

```
{!!HTML::script('assets/plugins/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js')!!}
{!!HTML::script('assets/plugins/jquery-isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js')!!}
{!!HTML::script('assets/plugins/classie/classie.js')!!}
{!!HTML::script('assets/plugins/codrops-stepsform/js/stepsForm.js')!!}
```

All the css, images and js are in public folder

Comment: You need your "static" files (styles, images, javascript) to be publicly available, hence you should keep them somewhere in your project's **public** folder. Take a look at this post, might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496301/laravel-5-0-folder-structure-public-vs-resources

Comment: this looks confusing . Are css , js , assets folder reside inside public folder ?

Comment: @Creator yes css, js, images are in public folder.

Comment: k so can you show how you have included them in your html file ?

Comment: @Creator Yes sure. I updated my Question

Comment: http://baselaravel.dev/customersocialpage/assets/img/demo/calendar_app.svg url does not looks good .  baselaravel.dev is your domain , and then url should be http://baselaravel.dev/assets/img/demo/calendar_app.svg . right ?

Comment: @Creator Showing "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://baselaravel.dev/customersocialpage/assets/img/logo_white.png"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86878/discussion-between-creator-and-sam-sam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as conversation with the OP ,there were some mistakes in including assets file . So they should be included in following ways :

```
<link type="text/css" href="{{URL::to('assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css')}}"></link>
<link type="text/css" href="/assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css"></link> \
```

Images

```
 <img alt="Cover photo" src="{{URL::to('assets/img/social/cover.png')}}" />

 <img alt="Cover photo" src="/assets/img/social/cover.png" />
```

There are many ways of including files , just depend on you which you follow .  [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149763/linking-asset-files-to-views-in-laravel4/23150113#23150113) link for including assets also . Rest laravel docs are always there. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you used relative links to assets (like `<a href="somelink"><img src="assets/img/demo/calendar_app.svg">Link</a>`), when absolute links meant to be used:

`<a href="somelink"><img src="/assets/img/demo/calendar_app.svg">Link</a>`

or, in more Laravel'ish way:

`<a href="{{ route('customersocialpage.index', $searchCustomer->customer_id) }}"><img src="{{ asset('assets/img/demo/calendar_app.svg') }}">Link</a>`

**Upd.**

Fix yours `{!!HTML::style('assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-flash.css')!!}` links to absolute links, or use [SerafimArts/Asset](https://github.com/SerafimArts/Asset) package, it will allow you to link assets on page like this:

```
{!! asset_link('less/style.less') !!}
{!! asset_link('js/jquery.js') !!}
```

...and even allow you to automatically compile LESS stylesheets and will take care about caching.